# Web Graphing Tool For Time scale data

Tags: php, javascript, graphing

I want to plot some data into a web graph control(preferably javascript or php). The data is collected regularly from a microcontroller, however the data collection interval is not linear. For instance, I may collect 5 data points in one day, and then 2 data points the next, and at different intervals etc...

Is there a graphing tool that can automatically create a linear datetime axis such that the data is represented properly on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery's jqplot does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqplot as James Cotter says, but there are also :

- Highcharts.js (apparently the best JS out there, but restrictive license)
- Google Charts Tools (generate a graph from an URL, it returns a PNG image)

Depending on your needs, I'd definitely use Google Charts Tools as it'd decrease my bandwidth usage. However, if you need complex manipulation of your datas once the chart is displayed, use Highcharts.js (or jqPlot).